Passport.js { message: 'Missing credentials' } error in Next.js
So I tried making the passport.js local strategy in Next.js using it's pages router (the app router can't work because NextResponse doesn't contain an .end() method like NextApiResponse). I have been able to fix most problems but then got stuck on this error:
Missing credentials error
My local strategy looks like this:
import passport from 'passport'
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local'
import { mockUsers } from './mockUsers'

export default passport.use(
    new Strategy((username, password, done) => {
        console.log("Username:" + username);
        console.log("Password:" + password); 
        try{
            const findUser = mockUsers.find((user)=> user.username === username);
            if(!findUser) throw new Error('User not found');
            if(findUser.password !== password) throw new Error('Invalid Credentials');
            done(null, findUser)
        }catch(err){
            return done(err, undefined)
        }
    })
)

And the api route I call and returns an error like this:
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import {NextRequest, NextResponse} from 'next/server';
import passport from 'passport'
import "../../passport/local-strategy";
 
export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    passport.initialize();
    passport.session();
    const body = req.body;
    console.log(JSON.parse(body));
    console.log("HERE1");
    const a = passport.authenticate('local',
        (err:any, user:any, options:any) => {
            console.log("Failed to authenticate");
            console.log(options);
    })(req, res);     // I also tried (JSON.parse(body), res) and (req.body, res)
    console.log("HERE2");
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Hello from Next.js!' });
    console.log("HERE3");
}

The error gets logged on the line console.log(options);. All the console.log statements I have to check to where the code executes run.
I also tried passing in (JSON.parse(body), res) and (req.body, res) instead of just req but that returned the same error.
The file where I am sending the post request looks like this:
'use client';
export default function Home() {
  const makeApiCall = async () => {
    await fetch('api/hello', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ username: "anson", password: "hello123" }),
    });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={makeApiCall}>Make API Call</button>
    </div>
  );
}

I can not figure out how to fix this error since everything from what I can tell looks fine.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!
When I tried creating the strategy I received multiple errors but fixed all of the. This problem I am having does not throw an error but is saved in a variable I have to print. I tried passing in all the different combinations of request and even just JSON as a parameter but the error stayed the same.
